# Is it safe to call virtual function from a derived class constructor or destructor?

Tags: c++

In Effective C++, author recommends not to call virtual function from a base class constructor or destructor. Then what about in derived class? Is it safe to call virtual function in a derived class constructor or destructor?

The book said,
"Once a derived class destructor has run, the object’s derived class data members assume undefined values, so C++ treats them as if they no longer exist. Upon entry to the base class destructor, the object becomes a base class object, and all parts of C++ — virtual functions, dynamic_casts, etc., —
treat it that way."

So I expected it would work like a base class if I called a virtual function from a derived class constructor or destructor. However, I've printed out the log and confirmed that it works like a derived class. (My execution environment is Visual Studio 2022.)

So I'm confused, Here's the possibility to think about.

1. This part of the book
   "Once a derived class destructor has run"
   means that it operates like a base class only after all of the constructor text is called,
   not as soon as called.
2. It does means that it operates like a base class as soon as called, but the rule is supported
   differently depending on the compiler.

Regardless of which one is correct, I wanted to find evidence with official data, but I couldn't find it. I'd appreciate your help.

## **1. Microsoft Document**

https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/cppcx/ref-classes-and-structs-c-cx?view=msvc-170

I've already checked the Microsoft document. However, only the following phrases could be found.

"The behavior of trying to access a member of a class that has already allowed the extinction to run is not defined. There is a high possibility that the operation of the program will be interrupted."

I don't know if this means immediately after the execution of the extinction or after the completion of all text execution. I don't know which way will be right because when I actually ran it, it worked well like a derived class as intended.

## **2. Chat GPT**

Chat GPT told me that it is safe to call virtual function from a derived class constructor or destructor.(As long as I'm careful about the initialization sequence)
But as you know, ChatGPT is completely unreliable because it needs information verification.

Comment: No. Remember that the whole thing about virtual functions is that the implementation can be overridden by a subclass that is not yet constructed. It should be safe if the class that you're doing it in has a `final` specifier. Otherwise, you can reasonably expect that the implementation you're calling is not the one you think you're calling.

Comment: You have misunderstood. *After* the destructor has run, the object becomes an instance of its base class for virtual-function purposes. *During* the destructor, it hasn't yet. Ditto *before* the derived class's constructor has run, and again, not *during*.

Comment: *"it operates like a base class only after all of the constructor text is called"* Basically yes. In constructors/destructors, the functions are always called from the current class or its bases, not derived classes.

Comment: If you had doubts, this should be convincing enough to never ask chatgpt about serious programming stuff. You should not call a virtual method from constructor or destructor.

Comment: It's safe, as in "it's well-defined in C++ standard". But it may not do what you expect - essentially, in constructor and destructor no virtual dispatch occurs, you will call the function as defined in class being constructed/destroyed. As [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#During_construction_and_destruction) explains, "In other words, during construction or destruction, the more-derived classes do not exist."

Comment: There is no reason to ask ChatGPT about anything. All it will do is regurgitate random Internet garbage.

Comment: Also, since MSVC is easily the least conforming of the three big compilers, I wouldn't trust MS docs on intricacies of C++ rules.

Comment: Also, on using documentation: The link refers to C++/CX, which is a different language.

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't know what it is talking about. It honestly even doesn't know "C" from "C++" and that is not even considering it has not been trained with good data to start from.

Comment: In short words: late binding is disabled on a class instance in its ctor/dtor; All member functions of the instance are early-bound; every member function is none-virtually callable. Virtual functions act virtual after the complete object is fully constructed until the destructor of the complete object begins; before and after that, each class calls its own overrides(if present) or its base overrides.

Comment: C++/CX is to C++ as JavaScript is to Java.  It is a darn shame that Microsoft didn't name C++/CX (and C++/CLI) something that did not including the characters "C++".